# How to skip a statement execution from the second time if I call the same page again in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

In my temp_file.php  i have a variable (array)

```
<?php
 $temp = array();
?>
```

No in my currentPage.php i am using this

```
<?PHP
   include 'temp_file.php';
   ///giving some value to $id and calling same page again
   array_push($GLOBALS['temp'],$id);   
?>
```

I want to use this temp array to append a value each time i call the same file(CurrentPage.php) but **include 'temp_file.php';**  statement is executing every time and i am getting single element to my array that i was last pushed.

Can any one help me is there any way in php to skip this include statement from second time to till the session end.

Comment: Can you not move `include 'temp_file.php';` to `temp_file.php`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
if (!isset($GLOBALS['included_temp_file']) || $GLOBALS['included_temp_file'] != true) {
    include_once 'temp_file.php';
    $GLOBALS['included_temp_file'] = true;
}
///giving some value to $id and calling same page again
array_push($GLOBALS['temp'],$id);   
?>
```

Comment: If i call the same page means(currentPage.php) again the statement include_once 'temp_file.php' is also executing again

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention *sessions* in your question, you must know about them. Then, why don't you store `$temp` variable in session, like:
`$_SESSION['temp'] = $temp`?

Comment: even i have tried like this but it is also starting session again and creating array and array index start from zero again

Comment: If it is starting a new session again, I bet you do not put `session_start()` at the very beginning of your script.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need ?

```
<?PHP
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['temp']) {
     $_SESSION['temp'] = array($id);
    } else {
       $_SESSION['temp'][] = $id;
    }

    $f = array_count_values($_SESSION['temp']); 

    if ($f[$id] < $Limit) {
       include 'temp_file.php';
    } else {
    // Error
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your array in $_SESSION, so your temp_file.php will become:

```
<?php
if(!$_SESSION['temp']) {
     $_SESSION['temp'] = array();
}
?>
```

and your current page like this:

```
<?php
   include 'temp_file.php';
   array_push($_SESSION['temp'],$id);   
?>
```

And you have to be careful to destroy your session variables when it ends.

Answer (score 0):

#### None of the answers are correct.

`include_once()` will not work for you, as you will be loading the page again, even if it is the second time, as with every load the `php` will execute from the top.

Because `include_once()` will only stop the redundant inclusion in **same** execution, not **multiple**.

Here is a simple workaround to your problem

```
<?PHP
   if(!isset($_SESSION['include']) || !$_SESSION['included'])) {
   // ^ Check if it was included before, if not then include it
       include 'temp_file.php';
       $_SESSION['included'] = true; //set a session so that this part never runs again for the active user session
   }
   ///giving some value to $id and calling same page again
   array_push($GLOBALS['temp'],$id);   
?>
```